# Solution to non-linear system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am looking for the solution of this bilinear ODE system:

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{dx}{da} &= aw(a)x(a) - bx(a) \\ \dfrac{dw}{da} &= c - dw(a) \end{align}$$

where we differentiate $x$ and $w$ after $a$.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this? Would help me a lot.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By after $a$ do you mean that $a$ is the variable?

Comment: No, I mean it is `dx/da = aw(a)x(a) - bx(a), dw/da = c - dw(a)`

Comment: @Moo: so is it in general possible to look at the equations seperately and first solve equation 2 and then substitute?

Comment: So, I would get this then: `w(a)=c/d, x(a)=C⋅e^(c/2d⋅a^2-ab)`. Is this correct?

Comment: From $\dot w + d w + c = 0$ you can solve for $w$ and then you substitute this function onto the $\dot x + b x - a w x = 0$